# Python: replace several slices in an array with single values

Tags: python, arrays, replace, slice

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(5)
x = np.random.randint(0,10,12)
# array([3, 6, 6, 0, 9, 8, 4, 7, 0, 0, 7, 1])
```

I want to replace several subarrays of `x`, each corresponding to a single value, e.g., avg. over the subarray:

```
# given the start and end indices for THREE subarrays of x
subary_start, subary_end = np.array([0, 2, 8]), np.array([1, 3, 10])
for i, j in zip(subary_start, subary_end):
    val = np.mean(x[i:j+1]) # avg. over the subarray
    print(val)
# 4.5, 3, 2.33
```

The expected output would be
    `array([4.5, 3, 9, 8, 4, 7, 2.33, 1])`.

In my typical case, `len(x)` can be ten thousands, and there can be hundreds of slices, so an efficient solution is appreciated.

Comment: Your solution works?

Comment: `np.mean()` is already implemented in most efficient way.

Comment: Are the start and indices for the slices always contained in separate ndarrays?

Comment: @wwii Yes it works, but kinda stupid: create a `True` ary of same length with `x`, set indices of slices to `False` while remain `True` for the start indices. Indexing `x` with the boolean array and set the start indices to corresponding replacing values.

Comment: @wwii I derive the `subary_start` and `subend_end` with the other function and I think the format of them is possible to not be constrained in this way.

Comment: @Wasi Ahmad Sorry I didn't make myself clear: I want an efficient replacing  scheme; the values used for replacement don't matter, `mean` is just for an example.

Comment: You cannot change the size of the array through assignment. You will end up having to create new arrays.

Comment: Agree, trying to figure out a better way under such constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import copy

def replace_slice(seq, slice_start, slice_end):

    seq = seq.astype(float)
    seq_copy = copy.copy(seq)
    bool_new_seq = np.ones(len(seq_copy), dtype=bool)

    for i, j in zip(slice_start, slice_end):
        bool_new_seq[i+1: j+1] = False
        new_val = np.mean(seq_copy[i: j+1])
        seq_copy[i] = new_val

    new_seq = seq_copy[bool_new_seq]
    return new_seq
```

`replace_slice(x, np.array([0, 2, 8]), np.array([1, 3, 10]))` yields the expected result. However, not sure if there is a better one for long sequence and list of slices.